# Group array by common id and date and summarize to calendar table

Tags: php, arrays, date, sum, grouping

I've been ripping my hair out on this one. Struggling with understanding how I really want to attack this problem, even the basic logic...

I've got this dataset:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 233773869
        [pid] => 9919304
        [tid] => 6754304
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-26T14:00:13+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-26T15:21:23+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-26T15:21:27+02:00
        [dur] => 4870000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (AP)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 13
        [project_hex_color] => #bc2d07
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 233719747
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742747
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-26T13:25:05+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-26T14:00:51+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-26T15:21:04+02:00
        [dur] => 2146000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 233647389
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742728
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-26T09:30:00+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-26T13:19:29+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-26T13:19:33+02:00
        [dur] => 13769000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
                [0] => mobile
            )

    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 233010371
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742769
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-22T15:50:46+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-22T16:42:10+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-22T16:42:14+02:00
        [dur] => 3084000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232948438
        [pid] => 9918365
        [tid] => 6753985
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-22T13:40:32+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-22T15:06:49+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-22T15:06:53+02:00
        [dur] => 5177000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (DS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 7
        [project_hex_color] => #268bb5
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232892530
        [pid] => 9888465
        [tid] => 6743039
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-22T11:40:16+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-22T12:19:35+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-22T12:19:39+02:00
        [dur] => 2359000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 5
        [project_hex_color] => #8ab734
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232878460
        [pid] => 9918425
        [tid] => 6754005
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-22T10:50:53+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-22T11:40:11+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-22T11:40:15+02:00
        [dur] => 2958000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (MK)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 13
        [project_hex_color] => #bc2d07
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232829038
        [pid] => 9918365
        [tid] => 6753985
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-22T08:15:19+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-22T10:56:25+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-22T10:56:29+02:00
        [dur] => 9666000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (DS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 7
        [project_hex_color] => #268bb5
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232828575
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742747
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-22T08:13:10+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-22T08:13:11+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-22T08:13:16+02:00
        [dur] => 1000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232828593
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742755
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-22T08:00:17+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-22T08:13:26+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-22T08:13:27+02:00
        [dur] => 789000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232818407
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742747
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-22T06:35:36+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-22T08:13:06+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-22T08:13:10+02:00
        [dur] => 5850000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232545676
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742755
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-21T14:30:37+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-21T16:58:14+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-21T16:58:16+02:00
        [dur] => 8857000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[12] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232487297
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742755
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-21T13:50:22+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-21T14:00:00+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-21T14:00:04+02:00
        [dur] => 578000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[13] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232477062
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742755
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-21T13:20:35+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-21T13:50:19+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-21T13:50:22+02:00
        [dur] => 1784000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[14] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232450760
        [pid] => 9888465
        [tid] => 6754026
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-21T12:01:52+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-21T13:03:24+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-21T13:03:27+02:00
        [dur] => 3692000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 5
        [project_hex_color] => #8ab734
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[15] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232448981
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742747
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-21T11:00:38+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-21T12:01:44+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-21T12:01:48+02:00
        [dur] => 3666000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[16] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232419408
        [pid] => 9888465
        [tid] => 6743039
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-21T10:33:44+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-21T11:12:49+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-21T11:12:50+02:00
        [dur] => 2345000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 5
        [project_hex_color] => #8ab734
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[17] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232392072
        [pid] => 9919304
        [tid] => 6754304
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-21T09:10:56+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-21T10:33:31+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-21T11:18:36+02:00
        [dur] => 4955000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (AP)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 13
        [project_hex_color] => #bc2d07
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[18] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232388704
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742728
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-21T09:00:49+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-21T09:10:51+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-21T09:10:55+02:00
        [dur] => 602000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[19] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232068791
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742755
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-20T14:28:28+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-20T16:06:54+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-20T16:06:59+02:00
        [dur] => 5906000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[20] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232028575
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742747
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-20T14:15:14+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-20T14:15:35+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-20T14:15:35+02:00
        [dur] => 21868
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[21] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232028704
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742753
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-20T14:05:32+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-20T14:28:28+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-20T15:35:02+02:00
        [dur] => 1376000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[22] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 232018213
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742747
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-20T13:50:56+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-20T14:15:07+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-20T14:15:10+02:00
        [dur] => 1451000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[23] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 231971266
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742769
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-20T11:36:17+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-20T13:41:47+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-20T13:41:51+02:00
        [dur] => 7530000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[24] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 231971175
        [pid] => 9886726
        [tid] => 6742755
        [uid] => 1502708
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [start] => 2015-05-20T11:00:04+02:00
        [end] => 2015-05-20T11:36:13+02:00
        [updated] => 2015-05-20T11:36:15+02:00
        [dur] => 2169000
        [user] => Fredrik Angell Moe
        [use_stop] => 1
        [client] => Internt (BDS)
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [project_color] => 0
        [project_hex_color] => #4dc3ff
        [project] => **HIDDENNAME**
        [billable] => 0
        [is_billable] => 
        [cur] => NOK
        [tags] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

The result I'm trying to wrap my head around is this (example):

```
___________________________________________________________________
|Monday         |Tuesday          |Wednesday      |Thursday|Friday|
|---------------|-----------------|---------------|--------|------|
|tid:6754304    |tid:6742747      |               |        |      |
|dursum: 9825000|dursum: 11684868 |               |        |      |
|---------------|-----------------|---------------|--------|------|
|tid:6584532    |tid:6523745      |tid:5474124    |        |      |
|dursum: 9865000|dursum: 11684821 |dursum: 5221456|        |      |
```

Based on the date (first date in dataset is Monday) I want to populate the "Monday" column in the table. The data I wish to populate is the "dur" (duration) SUM of all of the "tid" (Task ID) for that date. Then for the next date in the dataset i wish to populate "Tuesday" column with the the same data applied for that date.

Is there any wise brains out there that can see trough this mess and give me pointers and (maybe) some sample code. I'm in deep sea with this one...

Comment: are Start and end dates in record  equal always?

Comment: They are rarely different. But it might occour that the dates for start and end isn't equal. The date wich should deside what day the data should occour on is the start date. @splash58

Comment: am i rightly understand  that you may use just start day and put in it all dursum?

Comment: Yes @splash58, and all "dur" for that startdate should be summed together. Before moving on to the next date and doing the same operations for that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm:

```
1. take today date
2. know day of the week as number
3. count monday and sunday dates
4. create empty array
5. walking along the array (foreach array as obj)
   if array[date] does not exist, add array[date] (obj->[start]) 
   if array[date][id] already exist, add dursum (obj->id obj->dur)
   else array[date][id] = current dursum 
6. format output
```

What from this can't you do ?

Comment: Looks good! The one thing i might be struggling with would be summing up the "dur" key in the array for each day.

Comment: $array[date][id] += $obj->dur then in result $array[date][id] will contain summ dur of id for date

Comment: Look's so simple... :p I'll try it, thank you so much @splash58 !

Comment: it is really very simple task :) If the answer you found as helpful you may accept it. Will be questions, you are welcome

Comment: $result = array();
 foreach($row as $data)
 {
  $tid = $data->tid;
  $timestamp =  strtotime($data->start);
  if(!isset($result[$timestamp]))
  {
   $result[$timestamp] = $timestamp;
  }
  if(isset($result[$timestamp][$tid])){
   $result[$timestamp][$tid] += $data->dur;
  }else{
   $result[$timestamp][$tid] = $data->dur;
  }
 }

I've got this code now.. Giving me this warning: Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in...

Any help would be much appriciated!

Comment: I rewrite the code, because timestamp include time but not date only. Look there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78836/discussion-between-splash58-and-fredrik-angell-moe).